# air writeObject() not writing arrays properly

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, air

When creating an array and assigning a value to element 32 or 36 or 40 or 44 or .... before assigning a value to element 0 causes writeObject() to behave very strange. The following code should be sufficient to reproduce it:

```
var array:Array = new Array();
//array[0]=0;
array[32]=1;
array[0]=0;
var  byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
byteArray.writeObject(array);
byteArray.position=0;
array = byteArray.readObject();
trace(array)              //1
trace(array[0])           //1
```

This is clearly not what is expected from this code and stangely if the line that is now a comment is added it does work normally. Also changing the 32 into a lower number or something that is not a mutiple of 4 removes the problem too.

My question: Can anyone confirm to have the same problem and how do I fix it?
I am currently using flash builder 4.7 and had the same problem with flash professional 5.5 but not with the debugger of flash 5.5. Also I did not have this problem with an action script file in flash 5.5 but only with air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have two mistakes in your code.

- `byteArray.writeObject();` should be : `byteArray.writeObject(array);` according to Adobe about [byteArray.writeObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeObject%28%29).
- `byteArray.readObject(array);` should be `byteArray.readObject();` according to [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readObject%28%29).

Which will give you this code :

```
var array:Array = new Array();      
    array[15] = 15;
    array[0] = 0;
    array[32] = 1;
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    byteArray.writeObject(array);
    byteArray.position = 0;
var a:Array = byteArray.readObject();
    trace(a.length);        // gives : 33
    trace(a);               // gives : 0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1
    trace(a[0]);            // gives : 0
```

**Edit :**

[image]

**Edit 2 :**

You can also use `Object` instead of `Array`, like this :

```
trace('AIR version : ' + NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion); 
// AIR version : 15.0.0.356

var obj:Object = {}
    obj[2014] = 2015;
    obj[15] = 15;
    obj[32] = 1;    
    obj[0] = 0;

var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    byteArray.writeObject(obj);
    byteArray.position = 0;

var o:Object = byteArray.readObject();      
    for(var attr:String in o){
        trace(attr + ' = ' + o[attr]);
    }
    // gives : 
    // 32 = 1
    // 0 = 0
    // 2014 = 2015
    // 15 = 15
```

Hope that can help you.

Comment: That mistake was only in the code I posted here, not in the code I actually ran (it would trow errors ofcourse). But the traces still both only give 1 when I run it though. The code you posted give me as result: 
16
1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15
1

Comment: What are you using when compiled the code that I posted ? I tested it in Flash CS5.5, AIR 2.6.

Comment: Did you really publish and install it or justed tested the movie?(you probably tested it because tracing would otherwise be kind of pointless I guess) I only have this problem in flash 5.5 when I publish for AIR 2.6 and with flash builder 4.7 I always have this problem.

Comment: @10771158 I only tested it on dev environment, give me some minutes to create the app.

Comment: @10771158 After publishing, I got the same result as you. I think this is because of different versions 2.6 (dev) and 15 (prod).

Comment: So it is not incompetence or an messed up runtime on my side, which is good, I guess! But now, any idea of how to get this fixed?

Comment: @10771158 Give me some minutes to test it with Flash CS6 with AIR 15.

Comment: @10771158 I think that if you want to get all your array, you should put `array[32] = 1;` at the last, and this works fine with AIR 15 ( tested on dev an publish environment ).

Comment: Do you mean that putting 'array[32] = 1;' at last works with AIR 15 or that the problem doen't occur at all with AIR 15? And sadly I'm adding elements to my arrays everywhere all the time so adding element 32 (and 36, 40, 44,...) last is not really an option.

Comment: @10771158 Yes, that's it. Putting `array[32] = 1;` at the last works fine with AIR 15. I edited my answer.

Comment: I guess I should post this on the actual adobe AIR bug forum then. Do you have any idea if they actually do something with what you post there?

Comment: @10771158 I don't know if it's an AIR bug or just it's not supported , and even it's a bug, may be they take time to revise it. Try their forum. I put another edit about using `Object` instead of `Array` and It works fine without any order, try it.

Comment: I don't see why arrays would not be supported properly buy I guess I should be using arrays less than I'm doing now anyway. Object works fine but would it not be a better idea to use dictionary instead as a replacement of arrays?

Comment: @10771158 I think in your case `Object` is better than `Dictionary`.